# Listview Returns Exception when Adapter is Modified

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a ListView that displays some amount of data, and has a button at the bottom that can be pressed to load more data. This happens as follows:

```
CustomArrayAdapter a = GetInitialData();
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = 
   (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATR_SERVICE );
LinearLayout ll = 
   (LinearLayout)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.more_button_layout, null, false);
Button b = (Button)ll.findViewById(R.id.more_button);

b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    a.loadNextPage();
  }
});

lv.addFooterView(ll);
lv.setAdapter(a);
```

The problem is that whenever I press the button, I get a ConcurrentModificationException in the iterator that the adapter owns. I believe that this is caused by the fact that loadNextPage() is being called while something is iterating through the list, but I can't figure out how to make this not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

See the following URL
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/05/avoid-concurrentmodificationexception.html

or Try with **CopyOnWriteArrayList**

This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.

For example, it is not generally permssible for one thread to modify a Collection while another thread -- or the same thread -- is iterating over it.

Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will thow this exception.

Example:

```
for (Iterator it = myCollection.iterator(); it.hasNext()) {
Object myObject = it.next();
if (someConditionIsTrue) {
// myCollection.remove(myObject); // wrong can throw ConcurrentModificationException
it.remove(myObject); // right
}
}
```

Comment: The problem that I am having is that the list is being iterated over continually in order to display it - I know that this is happening, I just don't know how to get around it. I don't think that it is necessary to use a CopyOnWriteArrayList in order to do something so simple as a dynamically expanding ListView.